# Use a non-unique route key name?

Tags: laravel

We have rows which are sequenced and scoped to each organisation. So:

Processes tbl:

```
| id    | org_id    | sequence  | name                  |
|----   |--------   |---------- |-------------------    |
| 23    | 1         | 1         | New person            |
| 56    | 1         | 2         | Person leaves         |
| 84    | 1         | 3         | Person absent         |
| 26    | 2         | 1         | Something happens     |
| 34    | 2         | 2         | Something else        |
| 77    | 2         | 3         | And another           |
```

We do this so they can have a simple numbering system for their own records rather than a UUID, hash or something else. We prefer to have this in the url as well, so:

example.com/processes/1

Once logged in, we know their org_id, so for each query we can use `org_id` along with the `sequence` from the url.

Is there a clean laravel-esque kind of way to achieve this, maybe using the Model's `getRouteKeyName`?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the `sequence` column increment depending on the `org_id` column?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer with some help from the laracasts forum:

```php
/**
 * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($value)
{
    return $this->where('sequence', $value)
                 ->where('org_id', /* however you get your org_id */)
                 ->first() ?? abort(404);
}
```

Comment: You could additionally use a global query scope for the organization, to avoid querying data of another organization. By the way, do you have a unique constraint across these two columns in place?